# What is the best continuation in this problem-h4 or Qd8?

Tags: engines, analysis, problems

In the given diagram, I have two best ways to continue for white, which is the better option out of these two and why?

```
[FEN "2Q5/p1P2pkp/1p2p3/5p2/3P4/5P1P/P2q2PK/8 w - - 0 1 "]

1. Qd8 Qf4+ (1. h4 Qf4+ 2. Kh3 Qc1 3. Qd8 Qh1+ 4. Kg3 Qe1+ 5. Kh2! f4 6. Qg5+ Kf8 7. c8=Q#)2. Kg1 Qe3+ 3. Kf1 Qc1+ 4. Kf2 Qd2+ 5. Kg3 f4+ 6. Kh4 Qe1+ ( 6. Kg4 Qxg2 7. Kh4 Qg3+ 8. Kh5 Qg6+ ½-½) 7. Kh5 Qe5+ 8. Qg5+ Qxg5 9. Kxg5 1-0
```

Also would be interesting to see what line Houdini selects and how much will be the points for each of these two moves...

problem taken from [here](http://susanpolgar.blogspot.in/2013/06/sharp-eyes-tactic-review.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

4...Qd2+ in your main line is an error; instead Black should play 4...f4, after which he delivers perpetual check. White can try to play on with 5.Qg5+ Kf8 6.Qxf4 Qxf4 7.c8Q+ but that's still a draw. So 1.Qd8 does not work.

1.h4 enables White to escape from perpetual check, and wins.

Comment: `Qd8` still works for White win when White not choose `6. Kg4` as move. look out [my answer after](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/best-continuation-in-this-puzzle-h4-or-qd8/2480#2480).

Comment: @Ahmad Azwar Anas Black has already made a mistake in your 1.Qd8 line that includes 6.Kg4; as I said, he should have played 4...f4. So White does not get a chance to play 6.Kh4 instead of 6.Kg4 as you propose.

Answer (score 1):

Qd8 is the right idea but allows a pertpetual check after 1... Qf4+.  1. h4 removes all Black's hopes.

Comment: but if White choose `6. Kg4` as move, Black win the game. look out [my answer after](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/best-continuation-in-this-puzzle-h4-or-qd8/2480#2480)..

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas, I was answering the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

in my Houdini views, you're already win in your normal play, and long way to be draw. `h4` is already the best move.

Black should move `5. ... Qc3` rather than `f4`, `f4` makes Black will lose inmate at maximum 2 possible combination moves.

BUT

rather lose, if I follow your inner moves `Kg4` which give draw to White, in my Houdini views, I saw **Black** absolutely **won**.

as I can say, `Kg4` move is just a curse for White because of force-move check.. ^^

```
[FEN "2Q5/p1P2pkp/1p2p3/5p2/3P4/5P1P/P2q2PK/8 w - - 0 1 "]

1. Qd8 Qf4+ 2. Kg1 Qe3+ 3. Kf1 Qc1+ 4. Kf2 Qd2+ 5. Kg3 f4+ 6. Kg4 Qxg2 7. Kh4 Qg3+ 8. Kh5! Qg6+  9. Kh4! Qh6+ 10. Kg4! f5+
```

> **(0-1)**

Comment: As I note in my answer elsewhere on this page, 4...Qd2+ is a mistake. Black should play 4...f4, after which White must accept perpetual check or simplify to a drawn endgame.

Comment: oh.. literally maybe I wrong on read question.. my answer suggest possible winning move for **Black**.. ^^